# How to design real-time tracking system for android devices?

Tags: android, geolocation, scalability, amazon-sqs

I am working on project in which I need to improve/redesign existing real time tracking of Android devices. Android devices send it's location + few more metadata to our server in every 45 seconds and we update these details in maps to show device location. Android device has mobile internet connectivity through [GPRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Packet_Radio_Service). Current architecture is very simple we have servlet which our android device calls in every 45 seconds. This approach isn't reliable as server does not receive data from all devices in real time. If 100 devices are sending data then we receives data from 50-60 devices and there is always some good amount of delay in data to receive from device to server. As there can be 1000-2000 devices therefore scalability is another issue need to look.

Does use of messaging service like, Amazon SNS/SQS or Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) improve this problem? What are basic high-level of components need to make real-time tracking? If android device communicates to these service first and server gets data from these services, so it might solve the scalability problem.

Comment: How much research into the C10K problem have you done?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem

Comment: @ChrisK Not yet, actually I heard about this problem from you only. Let me do some research then I will come back to you.

Comment: any update regarding the problem?